# rails to find the average of an parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to calculate the average of parameters by passing them to an array but I am getting the following error. So I have doubt am I doing it right?

Here is my code

```
arr= @r1+@r2+@r3+@r4+@r5
    @current_user_satisfaction= arr.inject{ |sum, el| sum + el }.to_i / arr.size
```

Where I am getting r1, r2,r3,r4 from the DB. 
I am getting the following error

```
: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end @current_user satisfaction= arr.inject{ |sum, el| sum +... ^
```

What was my problem where is my error. I actually started learning ROR very recently.

This what I am writing to do

I have as set of variables which I am taking from db based up user_id and company_id
  the variables are

```
  @r1=company_rating.collect(&:r1)
  @r2=company_rating.collect(&:r2)
  @r3=company_rating.collect(&:r3)
  @r4=company_rating.collect(&:r4)
And I wanted to find the avg of all those variables.
```

So I am doing it like  arr = [@r1,@r2,@r3,®r4]
        @current-user_satisfaction= arr.sum.compact /arr.size 
But I am getting an error / is undefined and Why I am doing compact is because I have sum of the nil values in that

So please help how do this.

Comment: @BroiSatse has the correct answer, since you are in rails you can use the Enumerable `sum` method if you want i.e. `list = ["1", "2", "3"].map(&:to_i)` and then `@current_user.satisfaction = list.sum / list.size`

Comment: I have tried your solution but I am getting an error that / is undefined

Answer (score 1):

This is not an array!

```
arr= @r1+@r2+@r3+@r4+@r5
```

This is a sum. Should be `arr= [@r1,@r2,@r3,@r4,@r5]`
Additionally you missed dot between `@current_user` and `satisfaction`.

Also it is not as it should be done in rails. Could you show us how those variables are set?

Comment: Yes It is still going into an array it is not summing the data. I am calling those variables from db and and in sum of them will be nil.

Comment: Could you also show how you read `company_rating` - there might be much simpler way to achieve what you want.

Comment: I am not saying that you won't achieve it, I am saying there should be a better, more efficient way.

Comment: ok I just wanted notify that  I have solved my issue like, used arr=@r1+@r2+@r3 and and I have used @total=arr.flatten.compact.sum/arr.size Which I found in stackoverflow only

Comment: But I am really in need of help of this Question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21211594/rails-to-redirect-view-link-to-page-user-wanted-to-view-prior-to-login if you help me with this I am very much thankful to you

Answer (score 0):

First, You need to create the array like this

```
arr= [@r1,@r2,@r3,@r4,@r5]
```

The error you are getting is about the `.` dot you missed between `@current_user` and `satisfaction`. Change it accordingly and you will get it working.

As far as I think, you don't need an array there. if you are doing, `arr= @r1+@r2+@r3+@r4+@r5`, it is already calculating the sum of values, why you need to put them to array and go for a loop.

However, If you still want to use array, instead of `arr.inject{ |sum, el| sum + el }`, you can use `arr.reduce('+')`, which does the same thing of calculating sum of all array values. This has nothing to do with your problem, but makes your code more understandable.

Comment: in this line `@r1=company_rating.collect(&:r1)`, what is `company_rating` ? is it an array/collection of objects.?