# Rails to redirect View link to page user wanted to view prior to login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am new to rails I have an HTML.erb like this

```
<h1>books List</h1>

<table id="book" border="3" layout= "fixed" width=" 100%"  >

  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>

    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>

<% @books.each do |book| %>  
  <tr >
     <td><%= book.name %></td>

      <td><%= link_to 'VIEW', book %></td>


    </tr>
<% end %>
 </table>
```

Here I wanted to redirect to the actual books page the user wanted to view after user login where the login popup will come when user clicks the view button if user is not logged in. So how can I do it. 
For my Normal login from the menu screen I have written in applications_controller has

This is my application controller

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resources)
        if current_user.profile.blank?
            new_profile_path 
        else
            session[:previous_url] || books_path
        end
    end
```

So when user clicks on view button it should redirect to actual page he wanted to view after login. Can any tell me how to do this. I am using devise for authentication

Here is my books Controller

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user! ,  :only => [:show], 
    #:except => [:index] 



  def index
    @books = BOOK.all.order('rank DESC NULLS LAST')

  end


  def show
    @book = BOOK.find(params[:id])
    #@article.user_id = current_user.id 
    book_rating = BooksRating.where( :book_id =>@book.id,
                                          :user_id => current_user.id ) 



    @avg_r1 = book_rating.collect(&:r1)
    @avg_r2 = book_rating.collect(&:r2)
    @avg_r3 = book_rating.collect(&:r3)



    arr= @avg_r1+@avg_r2+ @avg_r3
     @current_user_satisfaction = arr.flatten.compact.sum / arr.flatten.compact.size if arr.flatten.compact.present?

  end




  def new
    @book = BOOK.new
end

  def create
    @book= Book.new(comp_params)
    if @book.save

      flash[:success] = "Welcome to my app"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end


  private

  def book_params
    params.require(:book).permit(:name, :place, :Description,:logo)
  end

end
```

show.html.erb

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>
 <h1> <b>Title:</b>
  <%= @book.name %>
</p></h1>
<p>
  <b>Logo:</b><br>
  <%=image_tag @book.logo.url(:thumb)%>
</p>
<p>
 <h2> <b>Author:</b></h2>
 <h2> <%= @book.author %></h2>
</p>

<body>
  <b>Description:</b>
 <h3> <%= @book.Description %></h3>

  <h3>Current User Satisfaction:- <%= @current_user_satisfaction %> <br/></h3>


<h2><b>Rating:</b></h2>
<table id="book" border="3" layout= "fixed" width=" 100%"  >
  <colgroup>
    <col style="width: 33%" />
    <col style="width: 33%" />
    <col style="width: 33%" />

  <tr>
    <th>Quality:- </th>
    <th>satisfaction:-</th>
    <th>does it cover all:- </th>

  </tr>
  <tr >
   <td><%= @avg_r1.shift %></td>
    <td><%= @avg_r2 .shift %></td>
    <td><%= @avg_r3.shift   %></td>


  </tr>

 </colgroup>
</table>






<br /><br />

 |
<%= link_to 'Back', books_path %>
</body>
```

The error

```
 Started GET "/books_ratings/user_rating?book_id=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-01-19 17:33:27 +0100
    Processing by BooksRatingsController#user_rating as */*
      Parameters: {"book_id"=>"1"}
    Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1ms

    NoMethodError (undefined method `profile' for nil:NilClass):
      app/controllers/book_ratings_controller.rb:72:in `user_rating'
```

My booksratings_controller line 72

```
  def user_rating 
   if current_user  
    book_id = current_user.profile.books.map(&:id)
    #rating = current_user.book_ratings.find(:all,:conditions=>["user_id = ? and book_id IN (?)",current_user.id,book_id])
    rating = current_user.book_ratings.where("user_id = ? and book_id IN (?)",current_user.id,book_id)
    if rating.size !=book_id.size
      if session[:book_id].blank?
        session[:book_id] = params[:book_id] 
        render :json=>"redirect".to_json
      else
        book_id = book_id - rating.map(&:book_id)
        @book_rating = current_user.book_ratings.new(:book_id=>book_id.first)
        @book = Book.find(book_id.first)
        session[:book_id] = params[:book_id]
        render :layout =>false
      end
    else
      session[:book_id] = nil
      render :json => "redirect".to_json
      # redirect_to book_path(params[:book_id])
    end
```

Comment: You have an extra comma at the end of your before_filer that shouldn't be there.

Comment: I have removed the comma but it is not working

Comment: Please be more specific what happens, how? when? Do you get any error messages? If so post them, otherwise its really hard to help when you only say it is not working.

Comment: Actually link view is not working it is in inactive when I click on it. And I am not getting any error message. It works only when I login and click on view.

Comment: You have an extra <% end %> two lines below <&= link_to 'VIEW', book %> in index view

Comment: I have corrected that one also but Still it is same condition which I mentioned above.  I forgot to remove here while updating. If it is ok with you, I can share my screen with you through skype or other

Comment: If you could push the code to github i could look at it.

Comment: Pierre I have noticed an error in my log file which I have updated above please have look.

Comment: @Pierre I have updated with rating controller too please have a look and tell what is my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using devise?

```
session[:previous_url]
```

Contains the **previous url**.

So you could do something like this

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resources)
        if current_user.profile.blank?
            new_profile_path 
        else
            session[:previous_url] || root_path
        end
    end
```

so it will redirect to previous_url or root_path in case there is no previous_url.

**EDIT**

at the top of your books_controller.rb

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!, :only => [:show]
```

Now when any one tries to enter a show for a book view they will be asked to log in, after log in they will either be redirected to new_profile_path, the book they tried to look at, and if they happen to go directly to login page upon entering the website they will be redirected to root_path.

**2ND EDIT**

This code below is confusing, if a user is logged in you show a link to the book with the name of 'VIEW', else 'VIEW' is a link to a new_user_session_path. Now if a user is not logged in they will see the 'VIEW' to the log in path and will after login return to index because you sent them from the index view to the log in action.

```
<% @books.each do |book| %>  
  <tr >
     <td><%= book.name %></td>

    <% if !current_user.blank? %>
      <td><%= link_to 'VIEW', book %></td>
    <%else%>
      <td><%= link_to 'VIEW', new_user_session_path,:class=>"login" %></td>
    <%end %> 
    </tr>
<% end %>
```

If you instead of having two alternatives you can simply link to the 'VIEW', book. And the filter itself will send the user to the login action and return them to the book they tried to view. Replace above code with this.

```
<% @books.each do |book| %>  
  <tr >
     <td><%= book.name %></td>
     <td><%= link_to 'VIEW', book %></td>
    </tr>
<% end %>
```

**3rd EDIT:**

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!, :only => [:show],
```

should not have a comma at the end

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!, :only => [:show]
```

Comment: No it is still loading to the index page.

Comment: Previous url is always the url before you log in, so if a user is at the index page and you redirect them to log in, they will be redirected to index. But if a they are at a show view the user will be redirected to the show view after log in

Comment: No I dont want like that, what I am trying like in my index page I have some view buttons which will redirect to the next page what the user wanted to view but to view that particular page user will be asked for the login and then redirect to that. for example if the user clicked on view which redirects to book/1 page it should redirect to the books/1 page after asking the login popup after that it should redirect. Same view-> books/3-> askfor login popup-> books/3

Comment: Yes this will happen if you put a before_filer on the books :show action, then when a user tries to enter a book show page they will be asked to login and redirected to that specific book show view.

Comment: yes I have kept the same But it is still redirecting to the normal index page.

Comment: are you using the before filter i posted above?

Comment: Ok after inspecting your view i found the problem, check my 2ND Edit in my answer.

Comment: When I click on the view before login it is not responding any thing

Comment: Please post your whole books_controller, show and index view aswell as the application_controller in your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using devise gem for user authentication then just use

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!
```

Or if you have created your own authentication system then set session with this in login action:

```
def new
  session[return_url] = request.env['HTTP_REFERER']
end
```

And then after sign in

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resources)
        if session[:return_url]
           return = session[:return_url]
            session[:return_url]=nil
           return
        elsif current_user.profile.blank?
            new_profile_path 
        else
             books_path
        end
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved by problem by adding the path in the applications controller as

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resources)
        if current_user.profile.blank?
            new_profile_path 
        else
            #session[:previous_url] || books_path
           book_path({:id=>params[:book_id]}) 
        end
    end
```